# Cryptography in virtual currencies

Tags: cryptocurrency

Apart from bitcoins and altcoins, are there any other virtual currencies (like game currencies, gift cards or coupons) that include cryptography in their algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Is suppose you choose to not consider online payment, credit card payment with euros, pounds, yens, etc(which include cryptography in their algorithms)...

In the 90's, there was a company called Digi-cash funded by David Chaum: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiCash
The goal was to provide anonymous transactions to users and was based on his previous academic work about e-cash
 The company doesn't exist any more, but it's the best example of "cryptocurrency" not based on the "blockchain protocol".